# Designing instruction emulating swap on a MIPS ISA with only 2 registers

Tags: computer-architecture, assembly, processor, instruction-set, pipeline

In a typical MIPS ISA, you have only 2 working registers. But you have a large number of ALU units.

How to design an instruction to emulate swap?

Comment: `MIPS ISA, you have only 2 working registers` I beg to differ. Without interlocks, this would be a sure way to need lots of NOPs.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to implement a swap between registers when there were just two candidates was a flipping a status bit:
hardware register renaming.